# How to connect to a remote Docker container via JMX

Tags: java, docker, jmx, jvisualvm, java-mission-control

I have a Spring Boot application running in a container on a remote machine, which JVM parameters I have to use to connect to it through Java Mission Control or JVisual VM (via JMX)?

Answer (score 8):

Start the container with the following JAVA_OPTIONS:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=7012 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7012
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<public_ip>
```

Also, make sure you expose the same port you are listening inside the container (e.g. docker run container -p 7012:7012 ...)

Comment: I can't stress enough how IMPORTANT that "same port" remark is. It won't work if that's not the case.

Comment: @MihaiTodor you just solved my problem!  All the other instructions on how to connection remotely did not include this "gotcha"!  Thanks mate!

Comment: You're welcome! Even if you're running the container on a remote host and you want to do port forwarding via ssh to connect to it, the port on `localhost` needs to be the same as the port in the container. I'm not sure why that needs to be so, but that's what did the trick for me.

Comment: In my case I didn't want to expose JMX port publicly (mapped it as `127.0.0.1:9090:9090` in my docker-compose.yml), and do the ssh port forwarding when accessing it. The thing is that besides the same port "gotcha", I had to set `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1` as it didn't work with host's IP nor machine name.